# vue 3 mapbox-gl-draw How to react to events correctly

Tags: vue.js, mapbox, vuejs3, mapbox-gl-js

I have a code that draws objects on the map, but I don't understand how to save them and in which part of the code to respond correctly to events

```
mounted(){
  this.initMap()
}
methods:{
initMap(){
        this.map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: 'mapContainer', // container ID
            style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-streets-v11', // style URL
            center: this.centerCoordinates, // starting position [lng, lat]
            zoom: 13 // starting zoom
          });
      this.draw = new MapboxDraw();
      this.map.addControl(this.draw);
      console.log(this.draw.getAll());
      let tmp = null
      this.map.on('draw.create', function (e) {
        let tmp = e.features[0].geometry
        console.log(tmp)
      });
      this.draw.add(tmp)
    },
}
```